# Create irregular image from a image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to create a new irregular image from  a image on iPhone

User will select the irregular shape from his finger and i want to create a new image from

that selected irregular shape

Any Idea how the user will select the irregular shape from image using his finger

Thanks in Advance for your valuable response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just draw the (filled with colour) shape / polygon the user created (by touching) in a UIImage, then use that shape as a mask as instructed [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html).

To allow the user to "select" his irregular shape, you just have to use `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` ... the "touches" are the points you need for your polygon.